# Why open_ssl function returns strange charartes using DES-EDE3-CBC?

Tags: php, php-openssl

I have a problem with decrypting a hex string using the openssl_decrypt function. It returns strange characters.

The function is this:

```
     $ params_decrypt = openssl_decrypt ($ params_hex, "DES-EDE3-CBC", "e238a0d8c9d82a8083b878e2fafc76216d3d0776a63bdf39", OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, "cca6662d330");
     echo "<br> <br> string_decrypt4345643xxxxYaEs <br> <br>". $ params_decrypt;
```

Returns this on the web page configured for UTF-8

��Q���r�84fڱh�x^X�C#���-�~īx��*G%E-]}ȥ[�ڱ/��P7��U�s���.y�(`w����5SmK��!Q��6��1��:�4����]�����_5s�p&Mִ�R�rlI욎���A/N�2����J^{����vsb ��\�.�D��!�`�@�Ds� }���^�Z�c$�ŉ���֬�*eЏD�'��.�h$��oM)��z@v��-�,l��VNrP�Ӝ���*y��=�,{�n:Jū$��p֭�e�!t�r��6'?oV�Ʈ)�"I�(�[���}D?`��D?��9&r�]�A��5��Dj�L�d��ʾ�*������R���X������6�����bi�g�θo���}Y��W}\�"��`Ise��*kH淭���S�f[�m9s��:�ū��G5՜�Ng�0U����$y�r�=A�G�s�(5�v�iQ�?���lWT�ge�k��7��X��� :�P_X�i�&7�|v�����@�ݶU���%�o�YW13�Z��n��ԾK'A�~�蝷�$�`�����Y����k�s�$�?!�|�4~���~���jF��*���fI�Tkvd[����Ӫ�>���?j4( ܘ��%t���Ҝ�0쥟��D�

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I forgot to convert hexadecimal value to string.

```
$data = urlencode($_GET["PARAM"]);
            
       

 $method = "DES-EDE3-CBC";
        $key = "e238a0d8c9d82a8083b878e2fafc76216d3d0776a63bdf39";
        $iv = "cca6662d3304033c";
        $options = 0;
        
        // transform the key from hex to string
        $key = pack("H*", $key);
        
        // transform the iv from hex to string
        $iv = pack("H*", $iv);
        
        // decrypt
        $dec = openssl_decrypt(urldecode($data), $method, $key, $options, $iv);
```

Regards.